# WAMP object not found- URL not found on server?

Tags: php, html, mysql, localhost

I'm currently trying to complete this project for school and I would really appreciate some help. 
I have been trying to learn PHP so I could extract data from my HTML and put it into my MySQL (which I'm accessing through XAMP). I have a problem that says:

> The requested URL was not found on this server. 
>   The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.' when I press the register button. I don't know what this means? I have a table called usertable in the database Login so I feel like it should work.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'ocr2020');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'login');

$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$fname= $_POST['forename'];
$sname = $_POST['surname'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dateofB= $_POST['dateB'];

$s= "select * from usertable where name='$name'";
$s2= "select * from usertable";

$result= mysqli_query($con,$s);

$num= mysqli_num_rows($result);

$num2= mysqli_num_rows($s2);
$id= $num2+1;

if($num==1){
    echo" Username Is No Longer Available";
}else{
    $reg= " insert into usertable(patientID, Forename, Surname, Username, Password, Email, Mobile, 
    DateOfBirth) values ('$id', '$fname', '$sname', '$name', '$pass', '$email', '$mobile', '$dateOfB')";
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);
    echo" Registration Successful";
}

?>
```

As I said, I would really appreciate any help or advice. Thanks!

Edit: 
Here is the updated code having taken on everyone's comments:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);.

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'ocr2020');

mysqli_select_db($con, 'login');

$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$fname= $_POST['forename'];
$sname = $_POST['surname'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dateofB= $_POST['dateB'];

$s= "select * from usertable where name='$name'";

$result= mysqli_query($con,$s);

$num= mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num>0){
    echo" Username Is No Longer Available";
}else{
    $reg= " insert into usertable(patientID, Forename, Surname, Username, Password, Email, Mobile, DateOfBirth) values ('$id', '$fname', '$sname', '$name', '$pass', '$email', '$mobile', '$dateOfB')";
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);
    echo" Registration Successful";
}

?>
```

Here is the code from the login.php page which is where I press the 'register button' and it creates the problem:

```
<html>

    <section id="loginBox">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="login-box">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 login-left">
            <h3> Login Here </h3>
            <form action="registration.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Username </label>
                    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter your username" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Password </label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Login </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 login-right">
            <h3> Register Here </h3>
            <form action="validation.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Username </label>
                    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter your username" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Password </label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Forename </label>
                    <input type="text" name="forename" placeholder="Enter your forename" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Surname </label>
                    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Enter your surname" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Mobile</label>
                    <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Email </label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label> Date of Birth</label>
                    <input type="date" name="dateB" placeholder="Enter your date of birth" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Register </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try hard coding values in the query and running just the php file you posted here and see what that does. Btw `if($num==1)` could fail since it's only checking if the one record exists. You'd probably want something like `if($num>0)`. Now, if this works, then the issue could be in the form and its action's url, the path, and/or something in `.htaccess`. Enable error reporting to see if it shows anything. Edit: Are you running this as `http://` or as `file:///` in your browser?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks for the quick reply. I have changed it to ($num>0), just wondering, what do you mean by hard coding values? Sorry

Comment: `$name = "John"; $pass = "abc123";` etc. type of thing and not running the HTML, just the PHP / mysql you posted.

Comment: @Pintsize21 `$s2` is query string, you did not executed that and you applying `mysqli_num_rows` on `$s2`

Comment: @RiteshKhandekar Thanks for the reply, just wondering, how do I fix that? I'm would do a for loop like in python for i times to count the number of rows but I'm not sure what to do here or rather how to?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm just using my local host...also I tried that, I went to the php file and changed the values. After I've done that am I meant to load the website again or something? I did and still had an error and no change to my table.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Remove this line `$s2= "select * from usertable";` and this line `$num2= mysqli_num_rows($s2);` and this line `$id= $num2+1;`

Comment: Keep @FunkFortyNiner suggestion to change `if($num==1)` to `if($num > 0)`

Comment: The code may then run

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: To fix the error you actually mention, we would need to see the code from the page containing the link that you are clicking on when you get this error message

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks so much for your help, I have made those changes but it still isn't working. I've just included my login.php file as per your last comment. Is there anything wrong there? Also thanks, you are really helping me :-)

Comment: Is the first code you showed us in a file called `registration.php` ?

Comment: Or `validation.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly After I've put the edit, it goes registration php and then login.php

Comment: And which button are you pressing on the `login.php` form

Comment: This one: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Register </button>

Comment: Well that will be looking for a script called `registration.php` in that same folder as the running script lives

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's correct.. I'm sorry is there something wrong with that?

Comment: No, but as the error is `The requested URL was not found on this server` I thought we should check that the file existsed and in the right place

Comment: Oh my god, I wrote down 'validation' instead of 'registration'. I get what you mean, that file doesn't exist. I lost five hours because I wrote down the wrong word. Thank you so much for your help!